# What is the best Java IDE?

Tags: java, ide

I'm new to java development and have started out using eclipse, what other tools should I be looking at?

I'm coming from TextMate and Vim so its a big change, any advice?

Comment: Also, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408929/what-is-the-best-free-ide-for-java-programming

Comment: My favorite is IntelliJ IDEA, but there's NetBeans as well.

Comment: The question is a bit vague.  Eclipse is popular.  NetBeans may be popular.  There are others.  I suspect that the answer for this question will always be a variation of "Hands down, the best possible Java IDE is the one I use!  All others are terrible or I would use them."  Fill in the blank of "I use" with what ever IDE you prefer.  My answer is "Of course, Eclipse is the best because I use it."

Answer (score 2):

If you're coming from Vim, you can ease the change by using the VI capabilities available for common IDEs - both Eclipse and Intellij have VI plugins ([here](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin/) and [here](http://ideavim.sourceforge.net/)).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the best, but my personal favorite is [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org).